# JavaScript runtime error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Error I get running the below code block: "0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'".
Failing at the statement: $(this).dialog("close");

```
function DeleteReport(reportTitle, reportId) {
    reportIdToDelete = reportId;

    var buttons = [
        '<button id="btnYes" class="modalbtn" onclick="ConfirmDeleteReport();">Yes</button>',
        '<button id="btnNo" class="modalbtn" onclick="$.modal.close();">No</button>'
    ];

    ShowMessage('Are you sure you want to delete Report:' + reportTitle + '?<br>This action cannot be undone.', '', buttons);
}   

function ConfirmDeleteReport() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Report/DeleteReport",
        data: { reportId: reportIdToDelete },
        type: 'Get',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.codeResult == 1) {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
            else {
                ShowMessage(data["message"], "");
            }
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            ShowMessage("Error while proccessing ..", "Error, Report Not Deleted");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I suspect `$(this).dialog("close");` does not refer to your dialog.

Comment: What makes you think `this` is a dialog?